# Perform union in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sqlite, union

I need help in performing a union of the resultset and apply orderby in javascript.

```
var a1 = conn.executeQuery('select text,s1 from Table1');  
var a2 = conn.executeQuery('select text,s1 from Table2');
```

Now I need to perform the union of a1 and a2 based on 'order by s1' in javascript.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE. Also TAG correctly. Is this sharepoint?

Comment: javascriptttttt

Comment: There is no built-in `executeQuery` in JavaScript - I added tag sqllite. Please replace if incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the union in your query itself, and ask the database to do it. The syntax would be something like:

`SELECT text,s1 FROM Table1 UNION SELECT text,s1 FROM Table2 ORDER BY s1;`

This would give you the combined result set in a single ask.